# Regular expression for one path beginning with another in Bash

Tags: string, bash, split

I have a (relative) path pattern looking like this

```
this/is/*/it/
```

"this" is the root folder, "is" a child folder and "*" is a folder with unknown name.
And so on...

I have a second (relative) path and I want to know if it is a beginning of the first part. Examples for the second path are:

```
These must return true:
this/is/
this/is/definietly/it/

These must return false:
whats/this/
this/is/a/test/
```

There are only folders (no files). And there are always trailing /.

I want to use the regex in Bash like this

```
if [[ $string =~ "^PATTERN$" ]]; then
  :
fi
```

Is this possible or do I have to split the paths and not use regex?

Comment: What's your condition to get path as true result and path as false result ?.

Comment: True result when path contains /it/ folder in the end ?

Comment: True if path 1 begins with path 2.

Comment: `[[ $path1 == "$path2"* ]]`

Comment: @Fravadona i tried [[ "this/" == "this/is/"* ]] and it returns false

Comment: Oh, just invert it: [[ "this/is/" == "this/"* ]]

Comment: @Fravadona your example works. But I cannot use it because I have a wildcard on both sides. It looks like this [[ this/* = this/is/*/it/ ]]. But Bash only supports wildcards on the right side.

Comment: Bad feedback so I want to close it so my account won't get deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

With hardcoded paths, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
string1="this/is/a/longer/path"; #
string2="this/is/"; # prefix

if [[ $path1 == "$path2"* ]]; then 
    echo "true"; 
fi
```

I don't quiet understand why you would want to split the string. bash is quite powerful for String operations, when using it to call other programs to do your job.

As you mentioned in a command above:

```
[[ "this/" == "this/is/"* ]]
```

I think you might want to consider understanding regular expressions before applying them. Your statement cannot be true and it does not follow from comment. It checks whether `this/` is equal to a path beginning with `this/is/` which cannot be true in any case because the second path is the longer one. You might want to try out https://regexr.com/ for practice. Mind the Cheatsheet to the left.

Comment: The problem is $path1 contains an unknown folder...

Comment: Please be more precise what your requirements are. We can only help you if we know what you want. e.g. shall the script have parameters? should it recognize the current directory and be able to list contents within another? Also, before I help you further, please add some proof of own effort (where you are currently standing) as edit to your question ;-)